# SugarCRM validate fields before_save in Logic Hook

Tags: php, sugarcrm

SugarCRM Versión: 7.6

In modules Cases, I have two custom field
Reason and Subreason.

I want when Reason = Returns, Subreason must be required.

In the Edit page in Javascript the validate works, but in the list cases, in edit row, doesn't work.

I'm trying with a Logic Hook but nothing works

With

```
echo "Hi";
die();
```

The console returns

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0
```

SugarApplication::appendErrorMessage, not returns anything and Save

SugarApplication::redirect, returns error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to check in a LogicHook, as last resort, use 1throw new Exception("Error message goes here");`. I don't think Sugar will show the message in all cases though.
If you just want a nice and clean frontend solution that should work across all views, look into `SetRequired` Dependency Actions. You can define them using a PHP assoc array using SugarLogic formulas and they should affect all views (although not sure about BWC modules).
See https://support.sugarcrm.com/files/11123c9e-f402-11e6-a5b6-020c3285a1ab.pdf Page 313 "Creating a custom dependency using metadata"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use list view logic hook.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achievable via `before_save` logic hook

```
<?php

class CaseBeforeSave {
  public function validateSubReasonField($bean, $event, $arguments)
  {
     if (!empty($bean->reason)
         && $bean->reason == "Returns"
         && empty($bean->subreason)
     ) {
        // This would throw error on UI
        throw SugarApiExceptionMissingParameter('Subreason is empty');
     }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!